# How do I get the value of Radio button(react-radio-buttons) in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

How do I get the value of radio buttons , if I call **updateRadioButton** in RadioGroup, it results in error. I need to print as Male or Female in console using (react-radio-buttons). Radio Buttons are printing correctly but I'm unable to get the value. Thank you in Advance.

```
 class CreateUserComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state={radio:''}
    }

    updateRadioButton(e) {
        this.setState({ radio: e.target.value });
    }

    <RadioGroup horizontal>
            <RadioButton value="Male">Male</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton value="Female">Female</RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well according to the [DOCS](https://github.com/mu29/react-radio-buttons#usage) of this lib, `RadioGroup` has a `onChange` prop handler that you can pass that will return the selected value, and then you could set it in the state or pass it on.

Here is  small running example with your code:

```js
debugger
const RadioGroup = ReactRadioButtonsGroup.ReactRadioButtonsGroup;
const RadioButton = ReactRadioButtonsGroup.ReactRadioButton;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  onRadiochange = value => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RadioGroup horizontal onChange={this.onRadiochange}>
          <RadioButton value="Male">Male</RadioButton>
          <RadioButton value="Female">Female</RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-radio-buttons-group@1.0.2/build/bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @PremKumar no problem, iv'e added a running snippet with your code

Comment: Wow , Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 3):

From [this `react-radio-buttons` example](https://github.com/mu29/react-radio-buttons/blob/master/example/example.jsx):

```
class CreateUserComponent extends React.Component {
  ... 
  updateRadioButton(value) {
    this.setState({ radio: value });
  }

  render() {
    ...

    return (
      <RadioGroup horizontal onChange={this.updateRadioButton} >
        <RadioButton value="Male">Male</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton value="Female">Female</RadioButton>
      </RadioGroup>
    )
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add onChange event to RadioGroup.

```
class CreateUserComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state={radio:''};
    this.updateRadioButton = this.updateRadioButton.bind(this);
}

updateRadioButton(value) {
    this.setState({ radio: value });
}

render() {
 return(
   <RadioGroup horizontal onChange={this.updateRadioButton}>
        <RadioButton value="Male">Male</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton value="Female">Female</RadioButton>
   </RadioGroup>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

 But, e.target.value doesn't work . 

updateRadioButton(value) {
    this.setState({ radio: value })
  }

Comment: You are correct. I didn't notice that. I just updated.